# How to login with socket event authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

> I have no idea how authenticate login user with socket.io

> Authenticate user and socket server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All socket.io connections start with an http request.  You can do any authentication you want at that initial connection point.

You can also access any cookies such as a session cookie that may already exist to indicate auth that has already been done.

The socket.io library itself has [middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespaceusefn) that can be used to implement an authentication check.

And, finally, [socket.handshake](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#sockethandshake) contains the headers and other info from the original socket.io connect request that can be used later during any socket.io message.